# SharePoint 2010 - Backup Term Store as CSV

Tags: powershell, taxonomy, term-store

Is there any PowerShell Script to export the Term Store? I have not found any OOTB solution, only import as csv, but no export as csv. Is there a script which can export the Term Store as csv? (So that it is possible to import it in another environment.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this link:

http://www.kowalski.ms/2011/03/31/sharepoint-2010-export-managed-metadata-terms-from-the-term-store/

you might need to do some changes in the script given on that URL

Answer (score 5):

There is no tool for this in the UI. It is pretty straightforward using the object model. I have seen code samples in C# that could be adapted to PowerShell. Alternatively you could try downloading the [termset import/export tool](http://termsetimporter.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a no code solution check out the post here http://www.metaengine.com/2012/02/Export-and-Import-a-Term-Set-on-Office-365-with-no-code

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an Dev -> Int -> Production solution to migrate your term sets as well as the content, you need to copy the Term IDs as well. Otherwise your tagged content will not be bound the the terms any more. 
You can either write some custom code to achieve this, or check out **our commercial Taxonomy Manager Tool**: http://www.layer2.de/en/products/Pages/Taxonomy-Manager-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

(a bit late, but might help someone else)

This is a good tools to use: http://termsetimporter.codeplex.com/